# In MVC 2, How would you determine a file exists at the server using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

I know you can do this:

```
if( System.IO.File.Exists(
    @"C:\INetPub\MVCWebsite\Content\Images\image.jpg") ) { ... }
```

and you can do this to reference files in MVC:

```
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/image.jpg")
```

So is there a way to relatively check that "~/Content/Images/image.jpg" exists (in MVC?)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Typically in ASP.NET, you would use a combination of Server.MapPath and File.Exists

Inside of a controller in ASP.NET MVC, you could use Request.MapPath as follows:

```
string filePath= Request.MapPath("~/Content/Images/image.jpg");
if( System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` is supposed to be used instead?

Comment: Better check file existance with HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists('~/path/to/file')